# Question for essential sup norm

Tags: real-analysis

My book give definition of an essential sup norm on $L^\infty(X)$ where $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space, as follows,

> $\|f\|_\infty=\inf \{a\geq 0: \mu(\{x:|f(x)|>a\})=0\}$

I have a question: if $\|f\|_\infty=0$ does that mean $0\in \{a\geq 0: \mu(\{x:|f(x)|>a\})=0\}$?
Since, a set does not necessarily contain its inf. But if I suppose $0$ not in the set, then I can construct a decreasing sequence of numbers in that set that converge to 0, and by Monotonicity of measure I can argue $\mu(\{x:|f(x)|>0\})=0 \implies 0\in \{a\geq 0: \mu(\{x:|f(x)|>a\})=0\}$.

I am kinda confused, or this question I ask doesn't even make any sense.

Can someone explain where my logic is failing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is essentially correct. If $\|f\|_\infty=0$, we do have that $0$ belongs to the set you described.